# Remove parts of QGIS 3 toolbars using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5

How can I remove specific parts of QGIS toolbar?
I know I can remove toolbars using this line of code:

```
iface.fileToolBar().setVisible(False)
```

But what I want is to delete every icon in the **fileToolBar** except **save project** and **save project as icons**, using Python.

[image]

Comment: You can customize the QGIS GUI via `Settings --> Interface Customization...`. If you still need a Python solution, just iterate `iface.fileToolBar().actions()`, ask for each action's `objectName()`, compare to those you want to preserve and for those actions that don't match, use `iface.fileToolBar().removeAction(action)`.

Comment: Python solution is what I need, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize the QGIS GUI via `Settings --> Interface Customization...`

However, since you are looking for a Python solution:

1. Iterate `iface.fileToolBar().actions()`
2. Ask for each action's `objectName()` and compare to those you want to preserve
3. And, finally, for those actions that don't match, use `iface.fileToolBar().removeAction(action)`.